# Ubuntu touch. adb devices is not recognizing nexus 4

Tags: 14.04, application-development, ubuntu-touch

I am using ubuntu touch in my mobile nexus 4. adb was working perfectly and also adb helped to test some of apps I have created in my mobile. Now I am finding that adb is not working at all (ex: adb devices is not recognizing the device). So I am unable to do anything with the mobile from my Desktop(ubuntu 14.04) and laptop (ubuntu 14.04). Please help me to get out from this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Someone helped me with this on Google+  You need to enable Developer Mode by going to 'About this phone' in System Settings, then right at the bottom it says 'developer mode'  After that adb should recognise it fine.